# Compiling and accessing class at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, console, runtime

I am trying to add some specific modular functonality to my application, I need users to be able to create their own classes and then have them imported into the program at runtime, these classes will follow a specific template so I can call functions within their new class.

For example, a class could be: http://pastebin.com/90NTjia9

I would compile the class and then execute doSomething();

How would I achieve this in C#?

Comment: Typically you would do this by providing users with a dll that provides hooks in to your application. This enables them to create a dll which your app can then load.

Comment: I've used programs that let you simply drop a .cs file into a directory and have it compiled and run.

Comment: See Darin Dimitrov's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718329/compiling-code-dynamically-using-c-sharp

Comment: You can check out how LINQPad works: http://www.linqpad.net/HowLINQPadWorks.aspx.  Not quite the same thing, because users type the code in LINQPad's UI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your users have the necessary tools (such as Visual Studio, which they really *should* have if they're writing C# classes), they can supply you with a DLL, which you can then load dynamically:

```
private static T CreateInstance(string assemblyName, string typeName)
{
    var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyName);

    if (assembly == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException(
           "The specified assembly '" + assemblyName + "' did not load.");

    Type type = assembly.GetType(typeName);
    if (type == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException(
           "The specified type '" + typeName + "' was not found in assembly '" + assemblyName + "'");

    return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
}
```

The T generic parameter is there so that you can pass an `abstract` `class` or `interface` to cast the type instance to:

```
public interface IDoSomething
{
    bool DoSomething();
}
```

Your users inherit from this interface when they write their own class:

```
public class UserDefinedClass : IDoSomething
{
    public bool DoSomething()
    {
        // Implementation here.
    }
}
```

This allows you to retain type safety and call the class methods directly, rather than relying on Reflection to do so.

If you really want your users to provide C# source, you can [compile their class at runtime](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9019/Compiling-and-Executing-Code-at-Runtime) like this:

```
private Assembly BuildAssembly(string code)
{
    var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
    var compiler = provider.CreateCompiler();
    var compilerparams = new CompilerParameters();
    compilerparams.GenerateExecutable = false;
    compilerparams.GenerateInMemory = true;
    var results = compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerparams, code);
    if (results.Errors.HasErrors)
    {
        var errors = new StringBuilder("Compiler Errors :\r\n");
        foreach (CompilerError error in results.Errors )
        {
            errors.AppendFormat("Line {0},{1}\t: {2}\n", 
                   error.Line, error.Column, error.ErrorText);
        }
        throw new Exception(errors.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        return results.CompiledAssembly;
    }
}
```

Then, you just substitute the resulting assembly in the `CreateInstance` code above, instead of the externally-loaded assembly.  Note that your users will still need to provide the appropriate `using` statements at the top of their class.

There are also places on the Internet that explain [how to get an `Eval()` function](https://www.google.com/#q=eval+function+in+c%23) in C#, in case you don't really need a full-blown class.