# How to Invoke Method with parameters from text

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, lexer, templating

I am trying to develop a template engine in c# and in my concept I will need to read to read methods as well as parameters from text files.[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202381/reflection-how-to-invoke-method-with-parameters) shows something could be done , but it does not work if the parameter is also read from the text.Is there a way to achieve this?

```
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string returnValue = Execute("AMethod(\"Hello\")");
            //the result in retunValue is same as from code commented below:
            // string returnValue= AMethod("Hello");
        }

        public static string AMethod(string parameter)
        {
            return "xyz" + parameter;
        }
```

The problem here is how to write the **Execute** Method

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to ask.  Are you just wanting to pass a parameter into a reflected method?

Comment: Please review now , I have edited the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

The link you provided has the answer you are looking for. Look at the line

`object[] parametersArray = new object[] { "Hello" };`
and change it to

`object[] parametersArray = new object[] { parameter };`

Answer (score 0):

There are really 3 ways to accomplish what you are trying to accomplish:

1. Reflection (this is what is explained in the article you reference)
2. Reflection.Emit
3. Dynamic compilation

2 & 3 are more complicated and heavy weight, but depending on the syntax you are trying to achieve in your template engine, one of those *might* be the best way to go.  Reflection requires that you handle each aspect of the invocation--binding to the correct method, passing arguments as arrays, etc.  Dynamic compilation would allow you to take a line a C# code formatted exactly how you would write it in a .cs file, compile it to a new method, load the assembly, and execute it.  This is all a bit of a hassle, so if you aren't married to having to execute a string that looks like AMethod("Hello"), I highly recommend the reflection route.

Here is an example of what you are trying to achieve with pure reflection:

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string methodName = "AMethod";
        object[] parameters = new object [] {"Hello", "foo"};
        MethodInfo method = typeof(Program).GetMethod(methodName, BindingFlags.Static);
        string returnValue = (string)method.Invoke(null, parameters);
    }

    public static string AMethod(string parameter1, string parameter2)
    {
        return "xyz" + parameter1 + "abc" + parameter2;
    }
```

For examples of 2 & 3, you can take a look at this question: [Compiling code dynamically using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718329/compiling-code-dynamically-using-c-sharp)

Comment: Actually I was looking for  string methodName = "AMethod("Hello", "foo")";--to begin with.